# SSH Key trouble on Debian

Tags: debian, ssh

I've decided on using keys for my SSH connections and I'm setting them up, however, I'm encountering the following issue when running `scp`:

```
scp -P 88 .ssh/id_dsa user1@192.168.1.65:/home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Debug:

```
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.65 [192.168.1.65] port 67.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA e6:5d:9c:48:5f:5b:a7:a5:8a:b2:95:f0:71:aa:19:dc
debug1: Host '[192.168.1.65]:67' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: user1@virt
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

I've checked the permissions on the authorized_keys file, they are 700 as a topic on here suggested this could be a reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You copied your `~/.ssh/id_dsa` private key file to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote host.  That's not how authorized_keys works.

Delete the broken authorized_keys file on the remote host and try this:

```
ssh-copy-id -P 88 user1@192.168.1.65
```

This requires the remote host to allow password access (just once, so the public keys can be copied in), and will add your public keys to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on the remote host.

see `man ssh-copy-id` for more details and options.

If the remote host doesn't allow password logins, you'll have to manually add the public keys to the remote host.  You'll need to be logged in on both the local machine and the remote.  Then (on local machine) run `cat ~/.ssh/*.pub` and copy-paste the output to `~user1/.ssh/authorized_keys` on 192.168.1.65.

If you aren't logged in on 192.168.1.65 and can't login because of lack of keys, you'll have to get root@192.168.1.65 to edit your `~user1/.ssh/authorized_keys` file for you (and make sure the perms are correct).

e.g. you could run `cat ~/.ssh/*.pub > /tmp/mykeys.txt` and then email that file to root@192.168.1.65 with a message asking them to copy the keys into your authorized_keys file.

Comment: You're an absolute life saver. The issue was I was copying the DSA part which isn't needed, I got the root to manually add my id_rsa in the authorized_keys file. 

Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, you've now leaked your private key, the whole point of which is to keep it private. The prudent thing to do is to throw it away and start over with a new key pair.